# Migrating Updates from an Asp.Net 1.1 Web App to Asp.net 2.0 Web App in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, upgrade

I migrated a web app from Asp.Net 1.1 to Asp.net 2.0 using VS 2005. While I tested and debuged and the Asp.net 2.0 version, we made some enhancements to the 1.1 production version (requests from users).

I'd like to know the best strategy for bringing the changes in the 1.1 web forms into the 2.0 version. Is deleting the web form from the 2.0 project in VS 2005 and using "Add Existing Item" to get the modified the web form from the 1.1 Project the best approach? (Then I can right click on that web form and select "Convert to Web Application.)

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on what kinds of changes you've made and how significant they are, but I'd be inclined to use a Merge tool like Araxis.